# C# Extra Loop? List being utilized incorrectly?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, json, for-loop

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
   {
  class Program
   {
        //Attribute properties
        public class Attribute
    {
        public string attributeUIDKey { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }
        //There are several attributes per User. Each Row of the CSV document are all the attributes for one user
        public class RootObject
    {
        public List<Attribute> attributes { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Write the results to a txt file for testing
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\test\\testjson.txt");

        //I am initiating this wrong :(
        RootObject users = new RootObject();

        List<Attribute> csvList = new List<Attribute>();
        //Get the CSV file full of User Attributes. One row = one user
        string fPath = @"C:\test\csvTest.csv";

        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fPath);

        string[] json = new string[lines.Length];

        //Make array to separate User key to make API call in separate API class
        string[] userUIDkey = new string[lines.Length];

        //Since each line is a different User, every user no matter how many is their own line. starts assigning work
        for (int l = 0; l < lines.Length;)
        {
            csvList.Clear();//I know I shouldn't need this!

            //Split each line into a string array to assign to Item. Removing any empty attributes along the way
            string[] uDComplete = lines[l].Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            //Need that user Key for the API call later.
            userUIDkey[l] = uDComplete[0];

            //Begin going through each line
            for (int i = 1; i < uDComplete.Length; i += 3)
            {
                csvList.Add( new Attribute() { attributeUIDKey = uDComplete[i], name = uDComplete[i + 1], value = uDComplete[i + 2] });

                //I know this is wonky, I couldn't figure out how to intiate the RootObject, every try ending in a 'Null reference'. This works wit hthe "csvList.Clear()" 
                users.attributes= csvList;
            }
            //Due to how the API accepts the JSON payload, this serializes the array correctly, making JSON array per line
            json[l] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(csvList);

            //writing to the test file
            sw.WriteLine(json[l]);

            //Go to next User
            l++;
        }
        sw.Close();
    }
}
}
```

Alright, this takes a CSV file I make from a SQL query. I control the way it looks, and this is what I have chosen based on our DB design. 
[image]
You can build your own file, based on the image (take out the column names, I wouldn't use them and don't remove them in my code), and the above code will output in to the window and TXT file exactly what I want. (I used a find and replace to change company info, sorry if I missed some capitalization of replacements!)

But I know I don't need that

`csvList.Clear();`

Which I had to put in because I didn't figure out how to correctly initiate the 
`RootObject` Class to make a `List<Attributes> users`

2 part Question:
--How do I correctly initiate RootObject dynamically in my For loops?
--Is there a cleaner way to build a List based on my requirements?

(I commented as well As I could, Hopefully I am clear in my questions/comments! Thank you for any help!)